# How to avoid excessive cloning in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust, and like many before me set off to write a Fibonacci sequence iterator for practice.  My first pass used `u32`s and worked fine, so I decided to try to write a generic version.  This is my result:

```
use num::Integer;
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Fibonacci<T: Integer + Add + Clone> {
    nth: T,
    n_plus_one_th: T,
}

impl<T: Integer + Add + Clone> Iterator for Fibonacci<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let temp = self.nth.clone();
        self.nth = self.n_plus_one_th.clone();
        self.n_plus_one_th = temp.clone() + self.n_plus_one_th.clone();
        Some(temp)
    }
}

impl<T: Integer + Add + Clone> Fibonacci<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Fibonacci<T> {
        Fibonacci {
            nth: T::one(),
            n_plus_one_th: T::one(),
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this with a `u32` and a `num::BigUint`, and it works fine.  I'm concerned about all the cloning in the `next` method though.  In particular, I don't understand why I need to clone during the addition step.

I suspect there is a better way to write this using some of Rust's more advanced reference concepts, but so far I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to use a `where` clause like so:

```
extern crate num;

use num::One;
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Fibonacci<T> {
    nth: T,
    n_plus_one_th: T,
}

impl<T> Fibonacci<T>
    where T: One
{
    pub fn new() -> Fibonacci<T> {
        Fibonacci {
            nth: T::one(),
            n_plus_one_th: T::one(),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for Fibonacci<T>
    where for<'a> &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output = T>
{
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        use std::mem::swap;
        let mut temp = &self.nth + &self.n_plus_one_th;
        swap(&mut self.nth, &mut temp);
        swap(&mut self.n_plus_one_th, &mut self.nth);
        Some(temp)
    }
}
```

Specifically, the `for<'a> &'a T: Add<&'a T, Output=T>` clause reads as "for any lifetime `'a`, `&'a T` must implement `Add` with a RHS of `&'a T` and `Output=T`.  That is, you can add two `&T`s to get a new `T`.

With that, the only remaining issue is shuffling the values around, which can be done using `swap`.

I also took the liberty of simplifying the constraints elsewhere (you only needed `One`, not `Integer`).

Comment: One quick follow up: I noticed you didn't put any trait bounds on the struct itself, only on the implementations.  Is that a Rust convention?

Comment: @MarkTozzi It's mostly up to personal preference.  You can repeat the bounds everywhere if you want to make it more difficult to "mis-use" a type, but it seemed overkill for an example.

Comment: In case anybody is wondering as well: the "where for" construct is called (The Magic of) Higher-Rank Trait Bounds (HRTBs) and is documented here https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html